# Hermitian form Inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I had this question:
$V$ is Inner product space above $\mathbb C$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product. Given $a,b,c  \in $ V, and $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|=1$, and $a+b+c=0$. Find 
 $\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,c\rangle+\langle c,a\rangle$.
I managed to get 
\begin{align}
0&=\langle a+b+c,a+b+c\rangle \\
&=3+\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,a\rangle+\langle b,c\rangle+\langle c,b\rangle +\langle a,c\rangle+\langle c,a\rangle
\end{align}
and got stuck.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard about the property called "symmetry" in regards to inner product spaces?

Comment: I know that $ <a,c>=\overline {<c,a>} $

Comment: If  we write $x=<a,b>+<b,c>+<c,a>$, then collecting terms and their conjugates gives $0=3+x+\overline{x}=3+2\text{Re}(x)$, so we know the real part.  Can you find the complex part?

Comment: Not sure.. $x-\overline x$ ?

Comment: Try doing the same thing with $\langle a+b+c, i(a+b+c)\rangle$.

Comment: I tried..could'nt find the complex part..